# Redirect to page stored in table

Tags: oracle, function, redirect, oracle-apex

I have an application in which a user creates a form, for which several responsible persons are selected in this form and can edit this form.

As soon as the form is submitted, the corresponding page of the process is changed.
The page of the form and the respective responsible persons are saved in a separate table.
The function has to check whether the logged-in user with the user ID is entered in the table as one of the responsibles. The table for example Responsible1 contains a foreign key to the table USERS, in which the ID is located. As soon as it finds the responsible in the table, the function then should redirect the user to the corresponding page.

```
create or replace function forward_user(p_username in varchar2)
return varchar2
is
l_user varchar2(255);
l_branch_page number;

begin
l_user :=p_username;
 /*
    Get the target page depending on entry in table 
  */
select 
 page
 into l_branch_page
from 
FORM_PAGES  
where EXISTS (SELECT f.RESP1 from FORM f
left outer join RESPONSIBLE1 s on s.RESP1=f.RESP1
LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS u on u.ID=s.ID where lower(u.USERNAME) =lower(l_user)  )
OR (fp.RESP2 in
(SELECT f.RESP2 from FORM f 
left outer join RESPONSIBLE2 p on p.RESP2=f.RESP2
left outer join USERS u on u.ID=p.ID where lower(u.USERNAME) =lower(l_user) ))
OR (fp.RESP3 in (select f.RESP from FORM f 
left outer join RESPONSIBLE3 e on e.RESP3=f.RESP3
left outer join USERS u on u.ID=e.ID where lower(u.USERNAME) =lower(l_user) ));

return APEX_PAGE.GET_URL(p_page =>l_branch_page);

exception
  when no_data_found then
   /*Use current page as default page*/ 
   return APEX_PAGE.GET_URL(p_page =>1);
   end ;
```

I then call this function in a pl/sql process when the button NEXT is clicked.

```
DECLARE
x varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
x:=forward_user(:session_user_name);
END;
```

I have already checked the sql statements and they work fine, I get the corresponding page.
As well the function compiles successfully.
But when I click the button nothing happens, the user is not forwarded to the stored page in the table.

As well I tried to call this function in a branching process with the behaviour Function Returning a URL(Redirect) but as well nothing happens.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

- create a hidden page item (as you're on Page 1, let's call it `P1_URL`)
- you already have a process which runs when the Submit button is pressed. Its execution point should be "Processing". Rewrite the process so that it populates `P1_URL`, e.g.

  ```
  declare
    l_branch_page number;
  begin
    -- your query goes here; I'll redirect to page 4
    l_branch_page := 4;
    :P1_URL := APEX_PAGE.GET_URL(p_page => l_branch_page);
  end;
  ```
- create an **After Processing** branch (why? So that process (see above) first populates `P1_URL` item). Its behavior's type should be "Page or URL (Redirect)", and its target should be `&P1_URL.` (literally that - ampersand followed by P1_URL followed by dot).

That's all; when you push the Submit button, process will populate `P1_URL` item which will be used by the branch and redirect to desired page. Will it work? It worked for me, I've just tested it.

---

Function:

```
function forward_user (p_username in varchar2)
  return varchar2
is
  ...
  return apex_page.get_url(p_page => l_branch_page);
end;
```

Process: just one line:

```
:P1_URL := forward_user(:session_user_name);
```

Comment: Shortly, just rewrite the process so that it looks like this: `:P1_URL := forward_user(:session_user_name);` which can probably be simplified to `:P1_URL := forward_user(:APP_USER);` if that's what `session_user_name` actually contains.

Comment: DECLARE
l_branch_page number;
BEGIN
:P75_URL :=FORWARDING_TO_PAGE(:SESSION_USER_NAME);
l_branch_page:=67;
:P75_URL := APEX_PAGE.GET_URL(p_page => l_branch_page);
END; I tried this one but unfortunately it does redirect to no page but as well does not show any errors:/

Comment: Not P75_URL but P1_URL; my bad, copy/pasted code from my application where I used Page 75. Yours is Page 1, right?

Comment: I am actually on page 81 (so here I created the hidden item and the branching process and the after processing process (it is not a branching process right?) ) I just wanted no confusion here:), this is the actual code: DECLARE
l_branch_page number;
BEGIN
:P81_URL :=FORWARDING_TO_PAGE(:SESSION_USER_NAME);
l_branch_page:=67;
:P81_URL := APEX_PAGE.GET_URL(p_page => l_branch_page);
END;

Comment: Not really; I edited the answer and posted code you should use. Have a look.

Comment: I am getting this error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: error converting character to number, is it the case because the return value in the function is varchar2 and not number?

Comment: Page **number** is a number, is it not? Why do you return a string, then?

Comment: I thought the function  APEX_PAGE.GET_URL(p_page =>l_branch_page); returns a varchar2 and not a number

Comment: It does, but your FORWARD_USER function returns page number, right?

Comment: as return statement I got this in the function: return APEX_PAGE.GET_URL(p_page =>l_branch_page); as you can see above

Comment: So true, sorry, didn't pay attention. I reviewed what you wrote and edited my answer, posting what I think you should be using: function is OK as it is, but process can contain only one line as function returns URL.

Comment: or should I return the l_branchpage  of return type number instead?

Comment: It's up to you. But, as function already returns URL, then use it "as is", that's the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Can you tell me how "as is" can be used, you mean when I am calling the function?

Comment: I meant to say that you don't have to change anything, but use code I posted at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Ah sry have seen it now. When clicking on submit I am getting the error: Sorry, this page isn't available. I guess something is wrong in my function. I'll try to look at it again

Comment: It says that you're trying to redirect to a non-existent page. Looks like a table which contains page numbers contains wrong data.

Comment: I already had a look at it, but the table seemed fine. I think the problem is  with the url :f?p=101:F?P=101:67 . It redirects to this url but this of course won't work

Comment: Makes sense, actually. Branch should redirect to **page** (number), not the whole URL. Try to rewrite FORWARD_USER function so that it returns a NUMBER, and let it RETURN L_BRANCH_PAGE.

Comment: I changed the function to return number instead a varchar2, then I called the function in  the process like this: DECLARE
l_branch_page number;
begin 
l_branch_page:= FORWARDING_TO_PAGE(:SESSION_USER_NAME);
:P81_URL :=apex_page.get_url(p_page => l_branch_page);
END;, still getting the same error

Comment: I changed the branching process to URL definied by Item (Redirect), now it seems to work:) Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you made it!